# How can I set the color of one bar in a chart transparent?

Tags: excel, vba, graph

I am trying to print several graphs in an automatic way but I do not understand how to set the color of only one bar as transparent. I used the Array(RGB(x,y,z)) to set the colors of the other bars.

```
Dim Srs As Series

    Dim vColor
    Dim i As Integer

    vColor = Array(RGB(255, 255, 255), RGB(214, 212, 221), RGB(155, 153, 172), RGB(255, 71, 19))


    With Cht
        .ChartType = xlColumnStacked
        .HasLegend = False
        .HasTitle = True
        .ChartTitle.Text = Target.Value
        .ChartTitle.Font.Size = 11
        .ChartTitle.Font.Bold = True
        .ChartTitle.Font.Name = "BLK Fort"
        .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
        .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Characters.Text = "OCF Percentiles"
        .Axes(xlValue).MajorUnit = 50
        For Each Srs In .SeriesCollection
            Srs.Delete
        Next Srs

        For i = 0 To 2
            Set Srs = .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
            With Srs
                .Values = Target.Offset(0, 1).Resize(3).Offset(0, i)
                .XValues = Array("A", "D", "I")
                .Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = vColor(i)
            End With


        Next i
        Set Srs = .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
        With Srs
            .ChartType = xlXYScatter
            .Values = Target.Offset(0, 4).Resize(1, 3)
            .MarkerStyle = xlMarkerStyleCircle
            .MarkerSize = 6
            .MarkerBackgroundColor = vColor(3) ' red
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

this is the output, but I want the blank bar to be transparent.

[image]

Comment: Try `.Format.Fill.Visible = msoFalse`.

Comment: @BigBen Thank you! I have already tried to add that line after recording a macro to see the wording for setting the color as transparent, but I am not sure how to insert it in my code and make it run for all graphs. Can you help? Thank you!

Comment: In your `For i = 0 To 2` loop, add an `IF` condition (`If i = 0 Then`.. or whichever bar you want **"transparent"**). If it's true, use @BigBen suggestion. If not, use what you have (`.Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = vColor(i)`). I suspect that should do the trick

Answer (score 0):

You can adjust the transparency of the first collection.

```
   For i = 0 To 2
        Set Srs = .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
        With Srs
            .Values = Target.Offset(0, 1).Resize(3).Offset(0, i)
            .XValues = Array("A", "D", "I")
            .Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = vColor(i)
            If i = 0 Then
                .Format.Fill.Transparency = 1 '<~~~~~ Transparency was adjusted
            End If
        End With
    Next i
```